# Replace value in two dimensional array - Perl

Tags: perl

I have a two lines of inputs and I need to change the ref val `\ref{#1}` into the second line of first brace loop `{eq: AL element}`

Hence the output should be like

```
Rqs.~(\ref{eq: AL Element})(\ref{eq: BL Element})(\ref{eq: CL Element})
```

Input
`my $newline = '\newcommand{\rqnnn}[3]{Rqs.~(\ref{#1}), (\ref{#2}) and (\ref{#3})}'; #Ref value 'n' number of values
 my $texcnt = ' \rqnnn {eq: AL element}{eq: BL element}{eq: CL element} '; #brace count should be matched with the first line ref counts`

Code:

```
my $CurBrLoopMany = qw/((?:[^{}]*(?:{(?:[^{}]*(?:{(?:[^{}]*(?:{[^{}]*})*[^{}]*)*})*[^{}]*)*})*[^{}]*)*)/;
my (@newmatrix,@matrix,$refs) = ""; my $refCnt = 3; my $brac = '{([^{}]*)}';
$newline=~s#\\(?:re)?newcommand{\\([^\{\}]*)}\[(?:[^[]]*)\]\{([^\(]*)$CurBrLoopMany\}#
$matrix[0] = $1; $matrix[0][0] = $2; $matrix[0][1] = $3; $refs = $matrix[0][1]; \#print "R: $refs\n";
while($refs=~m/\(([^\(\)]+)\)/g)
{
    push(@newmatrix, $1);
}
for(0..$newmatrix){ my $ln  = $_;
$texcnt=~s/\\$matrix[0]\b$brac$brac$brac/$newmatrix[0]=~s{\#}{$1}; /eg;

\#use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@newmatrix;

#ge;
```

Output Should be:

`Rqs.~(\ref{eq: AL Element})(\ref{eq: BL Element})(\ref{eq: CL Element})`

Could some please advice where I am doing wrong in my code.

Comment: This `for(0..$newmatrix)` should probably be `$#newmatrix` since it is an array. Also I cannot see the closing brace `}` of that `for` loop